# GoogleCloudMessaging.register(...) method always returns SERVICE_NOT AVAILABLE

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement Push Notification for my application. First of all, I've used old/depracated DemoAcitivity sample and I succeeded to receive messages from server to my app.

Since it's deprecated, I gave it a try to new GCM API in order to implement the identical Push Notif. service. During this implementation, I mostly used the code provided here;

```
   http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html
```

In my code, each time I try to register my device to GCM, I get SERVICE_NOT AVAILABLE error. The method I use to register is the exactly the smae in the docs(linked above);

*private void registerBackground() {*

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Object, String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... objects) {

            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }                  

                regid = gcm.register(GenericUtilities.SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration id=" + regid;


                // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.

                // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the message
                // using the 'from' address in the message.

                // Save the regid - no need to register again.
                setRegistrationId(context, regid);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();

            }
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            mDisplay.append((String)msg.toString() + "\n");
        }

    }.execute(null, null, null);

}
```

And this is the manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.pushnotificationexample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!--
 Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages.

 NOTE: the permission *must* be called PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE,
       where PACKAGE is the application's package name.
-->
<permission
    android:name="com.example.pushnotificationexample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.example.pushnotificationexample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >        

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pushnotificationexample.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.pushnotificationexample.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.example.pushnotificationexample" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>               

    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: By the way I need you to inform that I don't use any IntentService class and I have a custom broadcast receiver class.

Comment: I had the same issue, in my case the problem turned to be caused by loosing the wi-fi connection. So, check if you are connected to internet and try again.

Comment: It's working if I use GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID). I don't think it's the problem but thanks anyway.

Comment: Please include your manifest in your question

Comment: Please see edit for the manifest

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure whether it would fix your problem, but the following line is no longer necessary and should be removed from your manifest :

```
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
```

In addition, you no longer need the following line (though it shouldn't have anything to do with the error you get):

```
<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

**8/23/13 EDIT:**

When I built my app with API 8 and declared in my manifest:

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>`

I didn't get this error.

After I built my app with API 10 and changed the manifest to:

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>`

I got this error. I don't know if it helps, since your targetSdkVersion is 17, so you may be using advanced features.

Comment: Ok. I'll give it a try and let you know the result.